# Is it okay to use the scope of one controller from another using a service?

Tags: angularjs

I was told if you need to share between controllers you should use a service. I have controller A, which is a list of news websites, and controller B which is a list of articles on the sites from controller A. Controller B contains the list of articles and an iframe to display the articles. But when you click on controller A it should fade out the iframe and fade in the list. In order to accomplish this I give Controller B's scope to a service that is injected into both controller A and controller B. My question is whether or not it's okay to do that.

Basically, I do this:

```
app.factory("sharedService", function () {
    var $scope = null;
    return {
        SetScope: function (scope) {
            $scope = scope;
        },
        ControllerB_Action: function () {
            $scope.doSomething();
        }
    };
});
app.controller("controllerA", ["$scope", "sharedService", function ($scope, sharedService) {
    $scope.onaction = function () {
        sharedService.ControllerB_Action();
    }
}]);
app.controller("controllerB", ["$scope", "sharedService", function ($scope, sharedService) {
    sharedService.SetScope($scope);
}]);
```

Comment: If the controllers are nested in the application controllerB can access the scope of controllerA via prototypical inheritance anyway. Or is that not hte case in your issue?

Answer (score 1):

I would say its not a good pattern, since basically, the `$scope` is an Object that represents your current view or DOM-State. A controllers (and/or `Link`-Functions of directives) are the Glue between this state and your Application-Logic - so in my opinion, the `$scope`-Object should always remain inside the Controllers/Links.

Therefore if you wanna share Data between 2 Controllers, you should extract what you wanna share inside the Service, but not put the whole scope there (since it has lots of additional information that you dont need and want inside both controllers).

What you can do is simply link the data you wanna share by reference - that way, your Service will also Sync the Data between the two Scopes.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a world of ways of doing this, but I'll tell you what I would do:

I'd make use of event emmiters.

**Disclaimer: I haven't tested this code**

Assuming that Controller B is nested in Controller A:

```
    Controller A

    var controllerBFunction_A;
    $scope.$on('EventFromControllerB',function(data){
         controllerBFunction_A = data.sharedFunctions.controllerBFunction_A;
    });

    Controller B

    $scope.$emit('EvenFromControllerB',{
                                              sharedFunctions: [
                                                controllerBFunction_A,
                                                controllerBFunction_B,
                                                someOtherObject
                                              ]
                                            });
```

I think this could work. In my opinion this has the benefit of selecting what you want to share between those controllers...but probably there's a more elegant way of doing this.